# How do I get back up on a ledge I jumped off of in Smuggler's Hideout?

Tags: bioshock

I jumped off here, went looking around, and came to a dead end. Now, I went back here, only to find I can't seem to get back up onto the ledge. According to the map, there is unexplored area I missed back up there, which is probably where I need to finish collecting the images of the enemy (the objective). Anyway, I've tried to get back on but I had no luck. Is there something I'm supposed to do?

[image: Ledge]

[image: Map]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to get back up on that ledge. That is a one time access point. If you explore some more areas you will find more spider splicers to photograph. Just go out and explore some more, like you should in this game. Remember "Jesus loves me this I know".

Comment: I killed all the enemies I can find. The enemy I'm trying to photograph doesn't seem to be there, either. Was there an event I need to trigger or something?

Comment: The event was picking up the camera, which you did by the sounds of it. Are you only staying the the one section of the map? I just played through that game again about 2 weeks ago and I remember going all over that map looking for the last spider splicer too. I think I found him near an area with a lot of pipes up high that are pushing out water, and near some little waterfalls from ledges.